# Bash script to read filenames and categories from a document and arrange files into folders accordingly

Tags: bash

I am working on a project containing many hundreds of files. The project comes with a documentation file (sort of an "Index") that contains the filenames and the category to which that specific file name belongs. e.g.

```
Filename1 > Category1
Filename2 > Category2
```

Now I want to arrange all files in such a way that "Category" becomes the "Folder" which contains all the files belonging to that category. i.e.

```
Folder1 contains all files belonging to category1
(And name of the Folder1 is "Category1")
```

Doing this manually would require significant amount of time because names of the files are not in order.

So how can I write a Bash script that can read "Filename" and "category" from the document and then create a Folder (with name "Category") and COPY all files belonging to this category into the folder?

**Edit:**

Maybe the example I gave in the question was very simple. The actual problem was a bit more complex than that.
Anyhow, I have been studying bash scripting for a couple of days and I have successfully created a script which does what I want it to.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to arrange files of the project "BodyParts3D" into respective folders
#The index file (reference.txt) is arranged in such a way that it contains three columns: Concept_ID, Name and File_ID (in this order)

#Variables I need to begin with (I know there is no need for that but just for my own reference
concept_id=0;
file_id=0;
name=0;
prev_concept_id=0;

#Start a while loop to read the file line by line

while read -r line; do

#Initiate a word_count variable that is reset with every "while" loop
  word_count=0;

#Start a for loop within the while loop to read the line word by word
  for word in $line; do

#Add the words in the line into an array
    array[$word_count]=$word;
    let word_count++;
  done
#Concept_ID is the first word in every line 
concept_id=${array[0]};

#File_ID is the last word in every line
file_id=${array[-1]};

#The remaining part of the line is the Name
  unset array[0];
  unset array[-1];
  name=$(printf " %s" "${array[@]}");
  name=${name:1};

#Unset the array so that in the next "while" loop, the array begins from the start
  unset array;

#If Concept_ID is a new one, then create a separate folder for it and copy the respective file into that folder
  if [ "$concept_id" != "$prev_concept_id" ]; then
    mkdir "$concept_id $name";
    cp "$file_id.obj" "$concept_id $name";
  fi

#If Concept_ID is the same as previous line, then only copy the file into the already existing folder
  if [ "$concept_id" == "$prev_concept_id" ]; then
    cp "$file_id.obj" "$concept_id $name";
    echo "cp";
  fi

#set the current Concept_ID as prev_concept_id so that the new one can be compared with it in the next loop
  prev_concept_id=$concept_id;
done <reference.txt
```

This completely does the job I want it to do. But could I have done it in a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a loop in bash is the easiest solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r f_name _ dir_name _; do
   echo mkdir -p -- "$dir_name"
   echo cp -- "$f_name" "$dir_name/"
done < category_file
```

Remove the `echo` commands when you have verified the output

Comment: Maybe I made my example a bit too simple... This doesn't cover what I want to achieve. I have edited my question. please have a look